# Create trigger in SQL using inserted table to concatenate data, but end up with two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger when inserting first name and last name (without email), it will automatically generate the email, but it gives me two rows. One is that the email is NULL, and the other is the correct result.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail
ON StudentInformation 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @FirstName NVARCHAR (50),
    @LastName NVARCHAR (50),
    @Email NVARCHAR (100)
    
SELECT
    @FirstName = inserted.FirstName,
    @LastName = inserted.LastName,
    @Email = inserted.Email
FROM
    inserted 


IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM inserted)
    
    SET @Email = @FirstName+'.'+@LastName+'@disney.com'
    
    SELECT 
        @FirstName = inserted.FirstName,
        @LastName = inserted.LastName,
        @Email = TRIM(@FirstName)+'.'+TRIM(@LastName)+'@disney.com'
    FROM 
        inserted
    


        INSERT INTO StudentInformation 
      (
             FirstName, LastName, Email
            )
        values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email)
END
```

[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBEw1.png)

Comment: What do you think happens when multiple rows are inserted in a batch? Probably some [invaluable reading](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something similar to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail
ON StudentInformation 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @FirstName NVARCHAR (50),
    @LastName NVARCHAR (50),
    @Email NVARCHAR (100)
    
    SELECT
        @FirstName = INSERTED.FirstName,
        @LastName = INSERTED.LastName,
        @Email = INSERTED.Email
    FROM
        INSERTED 
 
    IF (@Email IS NULL)
        BEGIN  
          SET @Email = TRIM(@FirstName)+'.'+TRIM(@LastName)+'@disney.com'
        END
            
  
    INSERT INTO StudentInformation (FirstName, LastName, Email)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email)
END
```

When a new record is inserted to `StudentInformation`, it is required to check whether the email is provided and create a new email address when it's not provided. So `INSTEAD OF INSERT`is used in my attempt above to do the checking before the `INSERT` statement.